# How to find rows missing by every group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

Input:

```
A:

ID col
1  a
1  b
1  c
2  a
2  b
3  x
4  y

B 
ID col
1  a
1  b
2  a
```

I want to for every ID in B, find rows in A but not in B by every ID.

Output:

```
ID Col
1  c
2  b
```

What I tried:

1. left/right join. I am trying something like `select * from a left join b on a.id = b.id where b.id is null`
2. except. `select * from a except select * from b`

but not sure how to modify it.

Comment: Why `3  x` and `4  y` not included in the output? they are in A and not in B!

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Edited to explain this issue.

Comment: You want rows not in B that are in A but ONLY if there is at least one row in B???

Comment: @SeanLange Yes.

Comment: You can't get rows that aren't in B, but in A when there is at least one row in B. By definition, a row can't be both not in and in B.

Comment: Except should be correct.... what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the values in `A` for which there are records in `B` with the same `ID`, but not the same `col`, you could do:

```
select
  a.ID,
  a.col
from A
left join B
  on b.ID = a.ID and b.col = a.col
where A.ID in (select distinct ID from B)  -- B contains this `ID` somewhere...
  and B.ID is null                         -- ...but not with the same `col`
```

Test it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3c8a/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `exists` and `not exists`.

```
select * 
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where a.id=b.id) --id check
and not exists (select 1 from b where a.id=b.id and a.col=b.col) -- col check
```